# Does Sencha 4 and 7.7 supports OpenJDK21

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, openjdk-21

We need information on Sencha 4 version and Sencha 7.7version supporting OpenJDK21 .
I couldn't get that information. Could you help us getting those information. Thanks.

Comment: ExtJS 7.7 works with any backend. If you create an API using OpenJDK21, ExtJS can exchange data with it without any problem.

Comment: If you are asking about the required Java version to build ExtJS using Sencha CMD, it can be found here: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.7.0/guides/compatibility_matrix.html

For Windows and Mac, there is an installer that is bundled with the correct JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha currently supports Java 8 & 11 for Ext JS 7.7. It is informed in discord channel that 7.8 is being worked upon to support Java 17 & 21 versions which is a upcoming version.